# Java 8 Stream indexOf method based on predicate

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I just encountered the situation that I needed to know the index (position) of an element inside a list, but only had a predicate expression to identify the element. I had a look for a Stream function like

```
int index = list.stream().indexOf(e -> "TESTNAME".equals(e.getName()));
```

but to no avail. Of course, I could write it like this:

```
int index = list.indexOf(list.stream().filter(e -> "TESTNAME".equals(e.getName()))
    .findFirst().get());
```

But this would a) iterate over the list twice (in the worst case that the element would be the last one) and b) would fail if no element matches the predicate (where I would prefer a -1 index).

I wrote a utility method for this functionality:

```
public static <T> int indexOf(List<T> list, Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
    int idx = 0;
    for (Iterator<T> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); idx++) {
        if (predicate.test(iter.next())) {
            return idx;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

But as this seems to be a really trivial algorithm, I would have expected it somewhere in the Java 8 Stream API. Did I just miss it, or is there really no such function? (Bonus question: In case there is no such method, is there a good reason? Is working with the index in functional programming perhaps an anti-pattern?)

Comment: Do you think the items in a stream should be indexed?

Comment: Iterate over the elements instead of indexing ... if `list` does not have O(1) access, you are turning this into an O(N^2) algorithm instead of O(N)

Comment: @BheshGurung No, not in the meaning that an indexed access should be possible (`get(23)`). But asking for the *position* of an element in a stream seems, at least in my case, not completely absurd.

Comment: @MFisherKDX Good hint, you are absolutely right. Will edit - although I am looking for a more elegant solution anyway...

Comment: Stream is per definition not ordered and as a such has no notion of concept such as 'position of an item'. Beware also the difference between index of any matching item / distinct item and first matching item.

Comment: Streams aren't indexed, so I doubt you'll find a more-elegant solution unless you change your data type to a `Map<Integer, V>` or something.

Comment: @Michal Well, `stream().ordered()` **is** ordered, and - had you had a look in the Javadoc of `Stream.findFirst()`?

Comment: @JacobG. I mean *elegant* in the sense of readability, not performance... As there is `findFirst()`, there is no technical reason why there shouldn't be a method like `countUntilEncounterFirst()` (what would be an `indexOf`).

Comment: Well, there's `Stream#dropWhile` in Java 9, but you'd still have to use an `IntStream` to get the *index*.

Comment: @JacobG. Interesting hint! `dropWhile(e -> !"TESTDATA".equals(e.getName())).count()` would do the trick, wouldn't it? Unfortunately, I am bound to Java 8...

Comment: @Florian Albrecht: The JavaDoc states the findFirst() returns any matching item unless the stream has encounter order.

Comment: IMHO, your static utility, with a for and if, is elegant and readable. It will never be more readable than that with the stream APIs.

Comment: @JacobG. Yes, but `takeWhile()` would, wouldn't it? My fault...

Comment: @JacobG. Ah, understood now. Sorry, read the Javadoc too fast.

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht Thinking about it, I think using `Stream#dropWhile` will work if you subtract the resulting `Stream#count` from `List#size`, but it's unfortunate that you're limited to Java 8.

Comment: @JacobG. And still, that would not *directly* help my fellow developer colleagues to understand the code ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your loop is not bad, but you can simplify it:

```
public static <T> int indexOf(List<T> list, Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
    for(ListIterator<T> iter = list.listIterator(); iter.hasNext(); )
        if(predicate.test(iter.next())) return iter.previousIndex();
    return -1;
}
```

You can use a stream like

```
public static <T> int indexOf(List<T> list, Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
    return IntStream.range(0, list.size())
        .filter(ix -> predicate.test(list.get(ix)))
        .findFirst().orElse(-1);
}
```

but this will become quite inefficient if the list is large and not random access. I’d stay with the loop.

---

Starting with Java 9, there’s the alternative

```
public static <T> int indexOf(List<T> list, Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
    long noMatchPrefix = list.stream().takeWhile(predicate.negate()).count();
    return noMatchPrefix == list.size()? -1: (int) noMatchPrefix;
}
```

which is really expressive regarding the task “count the elements up to the first match”, but is not exactly the same as “get the index of the first matching element”, which shows when there is no match, so we need to replace the result with `-1` then.

Comment: Thanks for the simplification! Good idea to use `listIterator()`. Still, I would love to have such a simple API available on the Stream or List interface...

Answer (score 2):

I'd say a simple solution would be to use an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html):

```
IntStream.range(0, list.size())
         .filter(i -> Objects.nonNull(list.get(i)))
         .filter(i -> "TESTNAME".equals(list.get(i).getName()))
         .findFirst()
         .orElse(-1);
```

Filtering out `null` elements will prevent this from throwing a [`NullPointerException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

Comment: Hm, will definitely work, but readability is slightly limited, I'd say... Most likely I would still end up putting this in a utility method.

Comment: The `null` limitation applies to my current solution as well, good hint.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I'll edit the answer to filter out `null`s.

Comment: If the list is not random access, then this is O(N²).

Comment: Yup!  And downvoters, explain yourselves! :P

Comment: In your second code, if you filter out the nulls, you won't get the correct index.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException That's funny, `null` elements would have to be mapped to something else, and I don't think it's worth it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    IntPredicate isNotNull = i -> Objects.nonNull(list.get(i));
    IntPredicate isEqualsTestName = i -> list.get(i).getName().equals("TESTNAME");

    int index = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                .filter(isNotNull.and(isEqualsTestName))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the concept of an "index" only has meaning in an "ordered Collection". A `Stream` can come from any `Collection` such as a `Set`; having an "indexOf" method would essentially mean giving the source `Set` a `get(int index)` operation. Not to mention that a `Stream` can also come from any other source but a collection.

Another reason is that the implementation of an `indexOf` operation is that it basically requires a stateful Visitor of the `Stream`s element type; stateful because it has to count the members it already has visited. Stateful operations and `Stream`s don't match well.

As for your utility function, I don't see why you'd write it your way and not like this:

```
static <T> int indexOf(List<T> findIn, Predicate<? super T> pred) {
    for (int i = 0; i < findIn.size(); i++) {
        if (pred.test(findIn.get(i))) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```